# Statements inside jQuery deferred functions fail silently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm having a jQuery issue which is making debugging JavaScript more of a bitch than it already is: statements inside of a jqXHR deferred function will fail silently if they fail, and I haven't found a way to capture this error. Consider the following example:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({type: "GET",
                   url: "test.php"});
xhr.done(function() { 
    a += b; 
});
```

Where a and b are both undefined. This should return an error, but instead all execution stops and I get no notice that anything has failed. If, on the other hand, I write the following:

```
function thisIsAnError() {
    a += b;
}
thisIsAnError();
```

it will fail as expected, logging "a is not defined" to both the Firefox error console and the Firebug console.

A Google search turned up nothing, perhaps there is some error-handling function in jQuery I've missed? Note that xhr.fail() does not capture this error because it wasn't the XHR that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.get()` function you are using has no `done()` method. I believe what you're wanting to attach your function to is the `success()` method. [jsFiddle exmample](http://jsfiddle.net/uG6Mf/) of it working.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object

Comment: Sorry, I should have used a more accurate example - I am actually calling my AJAX requests with $.ajax(), which DOES have a .done() function. Regardless, note that [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MW68w/) only logs one error, despite the fact that a is undefined and called in two places.

Comment: I just looked at that jsFiddle and it gave two errors http://i.imgur.com/TGn1i.png

Comment: Somehow I'm only getting one error. Looks like it must be something failing on my machine, not with jQuery itself. Thanks for the help anyway.

EDIT: On Chrome, I get two errors. Firefox, one. I guess I'll be debugging in Chrome from now on.

Answer (score 0):

One way of debugging js (and imo the best way) is to use the firefox of chrome extension, firebug. Firefox has a more advanced plugin than the chrome extension, but both work.

Alos, `.fail()` is not going to work, what you're looking for is `.error()`

Comment: I have Firebug. In fact, stepping through the code with the Firebug debugger breaks it - it will stop executing code silently when it encounters an error, but Firebug still thinks it's debugging.